# An error has occurred during the upload process in wordpress version 5.3.2

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails, errors

I need your help , i try upload to wordpress an image but there is error ‘An error has occurred during the upload process in wordpress’ , please help me find solution. ASAP

Note : this website http://eliteclub.co.id/

After i try with chrome or firefox had same problem, just preview this.
Please share opini and solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the image? Your host may have a max limit on the size of a file that can be uploaded. Try a smaller file and/or reduce the size/resolution of the image before you upload it.

Have you been able to upload files in the past? What is the file type? Have you uploaded that type before? Has anything changes since you were able to upload files? New plugins etc?

Answer (score 0):

I guest the problem not about image size, because mys size image just 44.5 KB and upload_max_filesize 128 MB. Error still the same "An error has occurred during the upload process in wordpress". Can you give me another opinion?

Thank You.